# How to transport SKAction between devices?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, nsdata

I'm trying to send a SKAction between devices but I've got some problem... could you help me please? This is my code to send it:

```
let movment1 = SKAction.moveTo(x: 1600, duration: 0.25)
    car.run(movment1)
    var positionToSend = movment1
    let dataSend = Data(bytes: &positionToSend, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: positionToSend))
    try match?.sendData(toAllPlayers: dataSend, with: GKMatchSendDataMode.reliable)
```

and this is how I receive it:

```
func receiveDataP(position: Data, player: GKPlayer) {
    let _ : SKAction = position.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
}
```

This is not working, in fact I was just trying...can someone help me rewriting the correct code? I'm getting mad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the whole `SKAction`, you can just send the necessary information needed to recreate the `SKAction` in the other device.

Here, I suppose an `SKAction` is described an `x` value and a `duration`. If `duration` is always 0.25 then you don't need to send the duration.

Create something like this:

```
struct SKActionDescriptor : Codable {
    let x: CGFloat
    let duration: Double
}
```

To create the data to send, use a `JSONEncoder`:

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data = try! encoder.encode(SKActionDescriptor(x: 1600, duration: 0.25))
```

And you can use a `JSONDecoder` at the other end:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let descriptor = try! decoder.decode(SKActionDescriptor.self, from: receivedData)
```

And then create an `SKAction`:

```
let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: descriptor.x, duration: descriptor.duration)
```

Comment: And if I have to pass two actions at the same time?

Comment: @AndreaCulot then you should always encode an array of descriptors.

Answer (score -2):

if you want it to hit some thing or make it more movable you could make it physically 
like that and try to use

```
  Player.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 1600, dy: 0)
  Player.physicsBody?.angularVelocity = 0.25
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gKRw.png)

am not sure but I hope it work;

Comment: This does nothing to help the OP, we do not even know if they are using physics